# How to Send Message Without Command?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'd like to set a Discord.Net C# bot to output a message if something (like an error) happens on the code that is constantly running.

How do you send a message to any channel without listening for a message?

All the tutorials create commands that rely on COMMAND to make the bot "reply" to you. Is this possible?

This my C# code.

I want Sendmessage without command.

```
    public async Task RunBotAsync()
    {
        _client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            WebSocketProvider = WS4NetProvider.Instance
        });

        _commands = new CommandService();

        _services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton(_client)
            .AddSingleton(_commands)
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        string BotToken = "my_token";

        _client.Log += Log;

        await RegisterCommandsAsync();

        await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, BotToken);

        await _client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);

    }
```

I tried this:

```
public async Task Announce() // 1
{
    DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); // 2
    ulong id = 123456789012345678; // 3
    var chnl = _client.GetChannel(id) as IMessageChannel; // 4
    await chnl.SendMessageAsync("Announcement!"); // 5
}
```

but I get an error saying `Errro- NullException - chl=Null`

How to fix this?

Comment: Pls change your bot token asap

Answer (score 2):

You're getting a `NullException` because you're re-creating the `DiscordSocketClient` in your `Announce()` method.
By looking at your code, I'm assuming you're using the `Discord.Net` library, in which case the class holding this method:

```
public async Task Announce() // 1
{
    DiscordSocketClient _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); // 2
    ulong id = 123456789012345678; // 3
    var chnl = _client.GetChannel(id) as IMessageChannel; // 4
    await chnl.SendMessageAsync("Announcement!"); // 5
}
```

should inherit from `ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>` looking something like this:

```
public class MyClass : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    //...
    public async Task Announce() // 1
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

allowing you to access a property called `Context`, which holds your initial instance of `DiscordSocketClient` that was used to connect using the provided token.

You can access other properties also, like the Guild, the User, etc.

Official docs with all the accessible properties of `SocketCommandContext`:

https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.SocketCommandContext.html#properties

In your case, to be able to get a channel, you have to use this in your `Announce()` method:

```
public async Task Announce() // 1
{
    DiscordSocketClient _client = Context.Client; // 2
    ulong id = 123456789012345678; // 3
    var chnl = _client.GetChannel(id) as IMessageChannel; // 4
    await chnl.SendMessageAsync("Announcement!"); // 5
}
```

That will fix your `NullException` at least, but still doesn't answer your question, so let's try this:

The `CommandService` class is in charge of executing the commands received by Discord by using the method `ExecuteAsync(ICommandContext, Int32, IServiceProvider, MultiMatchHandling)`

https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.CommandService.html#Discord_Commands_CommandService_ExecuteAsync_Discord_Commands_ICommandContext_System_Int32_IServiceProvider_Discord_Commands_MultiMatchHandling_

that method returns a `IResult` object, containing these properties:

https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.Commands.IResult.html#properties

You can get information if one of the commands failed to execute and why using those properties, this doesn't cover *all* of your code, but covers the commands part at least. You can use third party libraries like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/for/dot-net/) to handle the error handling across the whole application, or build your own implementation, say for example, using `try {} catch(Exception){}` blocks where you know errors might happen and handling the exception yourself.

Feel free to contact me if you want some more help with this.

Comment: First, i am sorry for the slow feeback ur Answer.

i read about ur Answer.

i do not know about C#, 

i think there's a problem with not understanding the C# structure.

i'll figure out the structure a bit more and the process with ur answer.

Thank you for ur kind and Thankful reply . 

have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so from what I can figure out, I assume you somehow have your `_client` in the method. To send a message in a channel which your bot is in you can do

```
await _client.GetGuild(guild_id_here).GetTextChannel(channel_id_here).SendMessageAsync("your messagee");
```

Comment: i find what's the problem.

maybe, i tried Re-Creating the DiscordSocketClient in my Announce() Method.

Thank you , ur Reply.